# Is there any limit of table row when sequelize.js creates a db table?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am doing projects using the node.js and npm sequelize modules. During the course of the project, mysql tables created using sequelize and the database containing the tables have disappeared with the log records. I have thought of several possibilities. Is there a case where the sequelize module drops the database if the table row becomes too large? And is row limit automatically set when creating table?

This is for a new Linux server, running MariaDB, node.js, sequelize module. In the past, I've tried on searching about mysql table row limit. Also I use sequelize.sync({force: false})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting `sequelize.sync({force: false})` can you do `sequelize.sync()` instead and see how works? Can you also please share some code, and let us know how large your tables are getting.

Here's is how I start sequelize in my app:

```
db.sequelize
    .sync()
    .then(() =>
        app.listen(PORT, () =>
            console.log(`==> API Server now listening on PORT ${PORT} in ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`)
        )
    )
    .catch(error => debugError(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code I am using.

const server = app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 8080!');

```
require('./models').sequelize.sync({force: false})
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Databases sync');
        });
```

});

I set up the database I want to use in models.js and define the table.
I created 4 tables and stored 6916, 36675, 19, and 10970 rows, respectively.

Comment: Please try it without passing any value to the sync method. So it will just look like sequelize.sync(). Sequelize wouldn't drop any of your rows just because you have too many. It's just middleware between your nodejs app and your database so it doesn't care how much data, or what data you store in the database.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I'll try again as you told me.